# Displaying different content for side menu within a single view based on User's Role

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
       <ion-item ng-if="Admin">
          Admin Side Menu
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item ng-if="!Admin">
          Guest
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item href='#/app/store'>
         Store
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item href='#/app/store'>
         About Us
       </ion-item>

       <!-- Admin Side Menu -->
         <ion-item ng-if="Admin" href='#/app/progres'> 
           Progress Tracker</ion-item>
         <ion-item ng-if="Admin" href='#/app/settings'> 
           Settings </ion-item>
         <ion-item ng-if="Admin" href='#/app/user'> 
           Manage Users </ion-item>
         <ion-item ng-if="Admin" href='#/app/report'> 
           Report</ion-item>
         <ion-item ng-if="Admin" href='#/app/logout'>
           Logout</ion-item>

       <!-- Guest Side Menu -->
         <ion-item ng-if="!Admin" href='#/app/guestsettings'>
           Settings</ion-item>
         <ion-item ng-if="!Admin" href='#/app/gusetreport'> 
           Report</ion-item>
         <ion-item ng-if="!Admin" href='#/app/guestlogout'> 
           Logout</ion-item>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Hello All, I am trying to access side menu content in ionic app based on user role but unable to write controller to access side menu according to user role, as i want to show different side menu content for different user role.

Where I want the basic options to be displayed to all of the users, such as store, about us etc.

I would also like to have several other options, such as manage users, Users Report etc, that will be displayed only to an admin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple primer, assuming that this is Ionic 1.
Please note that security is ignored here.

You need to fetch a user object from your server. Suppose the user object returned looks like this:

```
{
 name: "John Doe",
 email: "jdoe@example.com"
 role: "Admin"
}
```

You need to attach it to the scope:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/authenticate'
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {

  $scope.user = response.data;
});
```

then in the html template:

```
<ion-item ng-if="user.role == Admin" href='#/app/progres'> 
       Progress Tracker</ion-item>
```